# Research-methodology book in the form of a dialogue between professor and student

Tags: reference-request, methodology

I am looking for a research-methodology book, which is in the form of a dialogue between a professor and a student. Once I had this book and it is very helpful. Unfortunately, I lost it and do not remember its title, either. Does somebody know the name of this book?

Answer (score 3):

I found it. The title is:

```
Avoiding Thesis and Dissertation Pitfalls by Thomas, R.M. and Brubaker, D.L.
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PeterJansson Mohammed answered his own question. How can this *not* provide an answer?

Comment: As you probably know the system generates automatic texts to flags and this "answer" is just as easily a comment to the question. If the question indeed has one unique answer in the form of a specific book then the question is too narrow so the entire post is thus questionable. I hope you see the problem visavi the stated purpose of posting on this site.

Comment: @PeterJansson: I disagree. This could not easily be a comment, as it is an answer and answers do not belong to the comment section. Also, I do not see, why asking for a specific reference would be too narrow. The question is clearly answerable and could help somebody searching the same book. (By the way, the choices offered by the dialogue after *Delete* are really just canned comments and have no further effect. Thus there is no reason to use them if you feel that they do not apply.)

Comment: If we do decide to delete the question, then the answer given here would be a good answer to [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26415/research-methodology-books-for-beginners-in-computer-science-research).